# take last row of multiple transactions for distinct users

Tags: sql, spring, postgresql, jpa

I have a table which has a structure like this:

```
id
user_id
type
previous_amount
amount
current_amount
```

some of the records might look like this

```
id, user_id, type, last_amount, amount, cur_amount
1,    10,     CR,     20.0,     10.0,    30.0
2,    11,     CR,     40.0,     15.0,    55.0
3,    10,     DR,     30.0,     5.0,     25.0
4,    12,     CR,     5.0,      20.0,    25.0
5,    11,     DR,     55.0,     10.0,    45.0
```

I want the result to look like this:

```
3,    10,     DR,     30.0,     5.0,     25.0
4,    12,     CR,     5.0,      20.0,    25.0
5,    11,     DR,     55.0,     10.0,    45.0
```

The last transaction of user `10`, `11`, `12`. The number of rows should be equal to the number of users in the table. And the result should be the last transaction that user made. In this case, user `10` had a DR, user `11` had a DR, and user `12` had a CR.

how can I write this in PostreSQL? It would be even better if it is in JPA repository form.

Comment: Dont ask "how should i do this with JPA" when you dont post the entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres, this is easiest using `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (user_id) t.*
from t
order by user_id, id desc;
```

Answer (score -1):

Or you can do it like this

```
    SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT *
    , row_number() over(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY id DESC) AS RN
    FROM table1) AS A 
    WHERE A.RN = 1
    ORDER BY A.id;
```